# Why timer interrupts breaks ARM CMSIS DSP functions on STM32L4?

Tags: c, arm, stm32, microcontroller, keil

I have a simple function that performs mathematical stuff on some data. It works perfectly fine. However, if TIM2 interrupts are enabled, the functions never completes. Code is being stuck at some ARM CMSIS DSP function. When I stop the code with a debugger, the cursor shows up in one of the interrupts. Also, Keil debugger in such case does not allow to place breakpoints in some places.

The interrupt works at 10 000 Hz frequency. Function should take somewhat ~5 ms. Micro-controller: STM32L431RCT6.

Could it be that original ARM functions from [CMSIS DSP LIBRARY](https://www.keil.com/pack/doc/CMSIS/DSP/html/modules.html) can't be interrupted? Maybe problem lies elsewhere?

The function is presented below. Everything works if I turn off Interrupts before everything. Strangely, hard fault appears if I try to turn interrupts on again.

```
void FFTW(void)
{
    float32_t windowed[SAMPLES]= {0};
    arm_mult_f32 (signal_input, (float32_t*)WINDOW_PARAMS, windowed, SAMPLES);
    memcpy(signal_input, windowed, 4 * SAMPLES);

    arm_rfft_fast_init_f32(&fft_handler, SAMPLES);
    arm_rfft_fast_f32(&fft_handler, (float32_t*)signal_input, Output, 0);
    arm_cmplx_mag_f32(Output, Output, FFT_SIZE);
}
```

Comment: 10000? 1000 is standard for HAL. Do you have the correct interrupt handlers? All DSP functions are "interrupt friendly"

Comment: I programmed it to have 10kHz. Not sure what you call correct interrupt handlers. If you mean this line "HAL_TIM_IRQHandler(&htim2);", then yes. I didn't know DSP functions are interrupt friendly .Thank you.

Comment: How long does the ISR of the timer interrupt run? Did you check that there is enough time left for anything else?

Comment: I have no idea what this code is supposed to be doing, but a local scope array looks fishy and is almost never a correct solution to any problem in an embedded system. How much stack does it use? What are those functions doing with it? What's `signal_input` and is it modified from other threads/processes/ISRs? Why do you do a hard copy of everything?

Comment: when you slowed your interrupt rate down to 1000 what happened?

Comment: @Lundin: could it be "stack overflow"?

Comment: @TomV Yeah never rule out stack overflow, especially not when you get really strange errors that you can't make sense of. Or similarly strange and hard to debug: buffer overruns corrupting other memory locations.

Answer (score 0):

The bug disappeared when all the long vector allocations inside the functions were removed. E.g., instead of creating `float32_t windowed[SAMPLES]= {0};` I re-use other identical length array that's defined globaly in current c file. Thank's @Lundin for pointing out the heuristics.

Also, It's worth mentioning that FFT function returns complex array; therefore, it takes twice the length of an FFT output (2 bins = 1 for real and 1 for imaginary parts). I encountered overflow when trying to use shorter arrays.
The full solution looks like this:

```
void FFTW(void) {
    apply_window();
    arm_rfft_fast_f32(&fft_handler, signal_input, fft_output, 0);
    arm_cmplx_mag_f32(fft_output, fft_output, FFT_SIZE);
}
```

Here signal_input and fft_output is arrays of type float32_t of length 2 * FFT_SIZE. Meanwhile fft_output is float32_t of length FFT_SIZE.